# Group by in subquery not working as expect

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains multiple type and output criteria which decides if that is pass or fail, now I wanted to count the total and passed rows.

```
  create table test
  (
     type varchar2(4),
     val number(5),
     output number(1)
   );
  insert into test values('AB',2,0);
  insert into test values('AB',5,0);
  insert into test values('AB',6,1);
  insert into test values('AB',2,1);
  insert into test values('BC',1,0);
  insert into test values('BC',4,1);
  insert into test values('BC',6,0);

  select t.type,ti.total as totalcount,count(*) as passcount
    ,'PASS' as status 
  from test t, 
       (select type,count(*) as total 
        from test 
        group by type) ti 
   where t.output=0 and t.type=ti.type 
   group by t.type;
```

Throws below error.
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.

I am expecting the total count by group wise and passed count in output
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ef3f7/23 Fiddle link

Comment: `select t.type,ti.total` conflicts with `group by t.type;` Add `ti.total` to `group by` or aggregate it in `select`.

Comment: Your outer GROUP BY expression is missing ```ti.total```. Every non-aggregated columns must appear on the GROUP BY expression.

Comment: how can i achieve this resultset without selecting the type itself

Comment: Thank you, with adding the total to the group by it worked

Comment: @SivaRam . . . Desired results would help.  How do you know if something passed?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, my actual case was a bit complicated and there pass or fail determined by the multiple different status not simple as above example, to get a understanding I have created above example. With multiple inner grouping and as @UNOPARATOR with using all non-aggregated columns in group by I have achieved the result.

Answer (score 0):

Find types with at least one `1` ("good") `output`, count total and passed

```
select 
  type, count(*) as total, sum(output) as passedCount
   , 'PASS' as status 
from test t
having max(output)=1 
group by t.type;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to count the total and passed rows.

I think you want a simple aggregation query:

```
select t.type, count(*) as total,
       sum(t.output) as num_passed -- presumably "1" is pass
from test t
group by t.type;
```

This assumes that "1" is for "passed".  If "0" is for passed, you can use:

```
sum(1 - t.output) as num_passed
```

If the logic is more complicated, then use `case`:

```
sum(case when t.output = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_passed
```